# Java Polynomial singly Linked List Question

Tags: java

I have been trying to work on a linked list implementation I thought I had it nailed, but for some reason I can't work out how to add a new node to the list at the start of the list.

This was a polynomial addition method, everything else works as expected, but this section does not work as expected. It returns polynomial with no changes... I think I am missing something really simple but cant see it.

```
else if (power > polynomial.powerMax())
{

    Polynomial newlink = new Polynomial(coefficient,power);
    newlink.successor = polynomial; 
    polynomial = newlink;

}
```

Whole Method

```
    public class Polynomial 
    {
final static private int mantissa = 52;
final static private double epsilon = Math.pow(2.0, -mantissa);
private double coefficient = 0.0;
private int power = 0;
private Polynomial successor=null;



public Polynomial(double coefficient, int power)
{
    if (Double.isNaN(coefficient)) return;
    if (Math.abs(coefficient) < epsilon) return;
    if (power<0) return;
    this.coefficient=coefficient;
    this.power=power;
}

    public static void add(Polynomial polynomial, double coefficient, int power)
{
    if (polynomial == null) return;
    if (Math.abs(coefficient) < epsilon) coefficient = 0.0;
    if (coefficient == 0.0) return;
    if (power < 0) return;

    if (power < polynomial.powerMin())
      {
        Polynomial newNode = new Polynomial(coefficient,power);
        if (polynomial.successor != null)
        {
            while (polynomial.successor != null)
            {
                polynomial.successor = polynomial.successor.successor;
            }

            polynomial.successor = newNode;
        }

        else if (polynomial.successor == null )
            polynomial.successor = newNode;

      }
    else if (power > polynomial.powerMax())
    {

        Polynomial newlink = new Polynomial(coefficient,power);
        newlink.successor = polynomial; 
        polynomial = newlink;

    }

    else
    {
     if (power == polynomial.power)
         polynomial.coefficient = polynomial.coefficient + coefficient;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the references of variables are passed by value ([link](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)). That means if you assign anything new to the variable polynomial it will not have any effect outside of this method.

```
String x = "Foo";

public void change (String s) {
   s="Bar";
}

System.out.println(x);
change(x);
System.out.println(x);
```

Will print

```
Foo
Foo
```

You need to return the new Polynomial you created from the add method.

```
public static Polynomial add(Polynomial polynomial, double coefficient, int power) {
    ...
    return polynomial;
}
```

Comment: You mean: "In Java variables are passed by **value**, and references are also passed by value, which means the reference is copied".

Comment: Interesting.. Ok this WAS an old Uni assignment, and the Lecturer has given sections of Code. 

public static void add(Polynomial polynomial, double coefficient, int power)

Was given.. so this is incorrect ??